# Binding an empty string if value is non-null in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, string, binding

I would like to make a WPF usercontrol that shows a string when and only when the datacontext == null. I'm using the TargetNullValue attribute in binding to display a custom string when the datacontext is null, and that's working as intended. But when the datacontext is non-null, it just shows the ToString value, which I would like to get rid of.

Of course I could solve this easily by using a valueconverter, but I'd like to find a way to solve this with xaml only. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: When value is non-null, what you want to display?

Comment: @Rohit: In that case I want to display nothing at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want `TextBlock` to be shown only in case binding value is null, you can have trigger in place and set `Visibility` to `Visible` when **binding value is null** and otherwise `Collapsed` always.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetNullValue=NullValue}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a data trigger on `{x:Null}`. There are many options using styles, data templates etc., depending on taste and needs. For instance:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ShowOnNull">
  <TextBlock x:Name="text"/>

  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
      <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="your custom string"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ShowOnNull}" 
    Content="{Binding ...}"/>
```